# How can I merge an empty data frame and a data frame in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, rows

I'm trying to merge to data frames like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(hola = as.numeric(), toma = as.character())
data2 <- data.frame(hola = as.numeric(1), toma = as.character("cadenita"))
data1
data2

merge(data1, data2)
```

But it just doesn't work, when I explore each I get:

```
> str(data1)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ hola: num 
 $ toma: Factor w/ 0 levels: 
> str(data2)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ hola: num 1
 $ toma: Factor w/ 1 level "cadenita": 1
```

I can see, it may be about the character column (toma) but I don't understand what's happening, can anyone give a hand???

Comment: I have no idea why you want to do this, but `merge(data1, data2, all = TRUE)` works

Comment: @RichardScriven - i've had similar things in projects in the past. Select rows matching some selection criteria from one dataset, then merge with an existing dataset. If nothing matches the first selection, you're merging against an empty dataset.

Comment: Alright, I can dig it.

Comment: @RichardScriven - "CAN YOU DIG IT?!"  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-OYKd8SVrI

Comment: Is this surprising? Merge defaults to an inner join... no rows in one data frame => no matches => no rows in result. `all = TRUE` for outer join, `all.x = TRUE` for left join, `all.y = TRUE` for right join.

Comment: I just wanted to create an empty data frame to add rows later, but when I started adding using merge, I bumped into this problem. I think the question would become then, which way is the best way to add rows to an empty data frame, right?

Answer (score 0):

Reopening long time later, but I bumped into the same question. Answer may be useful to others.

What you are looking for is appending the table, not merging. If you are using `data.table`, then  `rbindlist(list(data1, data2))` will do the job. `Data1` may even be completely empty/undefined, i.e. `data1 <- data.frame()`